# TYPO3: list without pid restraint / recursive single table view?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-7.x

I have a TYPO3 extension with records that are distributed all over the page tree.

Do I really have to make a custom BE module to list and edit all those records? Or are there other possibilities to list them without the `pid` restraint from the pagetree?

I thought about search, which works on the content:

[image]

So I could include a keyword to search by for that record type. I saw there's `mod.web_list.searchLevels` to extend the search further down.

Maybe it's possible to bookmark searches?
EDIT: cool, I can bookmark searches!

Even more convenient would be if the [Single Table View](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InsideTypo3Reference/CoreArchitecture/CoreModules/ListModule/Index.html) could be tweaked somehow to work recursively, e.g. 4 pagetree levels down – is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my own answer already:

just make a bookmark of your search by clicking the "Star" button after having made that search.

[image]

When calling the page from the favourite menu, the search results will be displayed - awesome!

Not tested in real life yet, and maybe there are better solutions though?